# When will I encounter UK border control

Tags: lhr, british-airways, jfk

If I am traveling from NY to Mumbai, via London, what are all the possibilities/reasons that may cause me to go through UK border control? Eg: Changing terminal? Eg: Rechecking luggage? Anything else?

Comment: Changing airport? Flight cancelled with an overnight stay until the next one? Illness?

Answer (score 1):

- Claiming luggage (but there is an airside luggage check in Terminal 5
  if you have additional luggage to check in London)
- Changing airport
- Flight is cancelled/delayed and you have to leave because the airport
  is closing for the night (there is a procedure for this, you will be
  allowed out)
- Getting arrested (but the border formalities will be skipped, I think, in this instance)

As I said in your other question, you can move between terminals freely without crossing the UK border. You can ride the buses all day if you like.

Comment: Flight is cancelled/delayed and you have to leave because the airport is closing for the night (there is a procedure for this, you will be allowed out). Thanks ! Can you please append with some hyperlink of the procedure ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I don't think it is public information, perhaps because it could be seen as a way into the UK. You will discuss with the assistance desk if the need arises. If the airport is closing, special procedures will allow you to leave the airport, unless you are considered exceptionally high risk (I have heard of a guy getting locked in a disused office overnight).

Comment: @Calchas Isn't one of the terminals open overnight? Or has that finished now that T1 has closed?

Comment: There's only about a 4 hour window between the last flight leaving in the evening and the first one getting in.  I once stayed in T4 overnight, because I had an international flight at 5:30 am, so had to be there at 3:30 - and didn't fancy paying for a taxi, so I took the tube arriving to the airport around midnight and headed into T4.  While pretty much everything was closed, I just spent the next few hours on the bench reading or watching videos on the ipad. Once or twice security came over and asked me what I was doing, but nothing more.  And this was landside. Airside must be the same.

Comment: @AleksG Terminal 5 airside is not open overnight.